# Order of graphics creation and data processing in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm processing vast amount of data (>>100k lines) with variable step.

I would like to create figure and plot the processed data as they are counted (for termination of the running script when something goes wrong, or for impressing the "customers" with the fancy progress "animation").

Suppose we have `sourcefile.txt' with one column of positive numbers *X(n)* on row *n* and:

- There is plenty of lines with *X(n+1) < X(n)*,
- *X(n+N) > X(n)*; where *N* goes from thousands for small *n* to tens for large *n*.

I've thought of:

```
fID=fopen('sourcefile.txt');
figure;axes; % create figure
act='0';threshold=0;N=0;DATA=0;ii=0;
while ischar(act) % loop until end of file.
  ii=ii+1;N=0;
  while temp<threshold&&ischar(act) % loop until threshold is overflown (next step) or end-of-file is reached. 
    act=fgetl(fID);
    temp=temp+str2double(act);
    N=N+1;
  end
  line('xdata',ii,'ydata',temp/N,'Marker','o') % New point should appear
threshold=threshold+0.5; % Continue with new stopping rule.
end
```

The problem is that the loops are entered and processed and then figure is created. How can I force MATLAB to create a figure and then to calculate/update plotted data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inserting [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) after you draw the line using `line`.  This will flush the graphics buffer and update your figure immediately.  If you don't do this, your figure will appear blank until the loop finishes, and then the figure will appear with your objects that you added to the figure.

So to be specific with what I talked about:

```
fID=fopen('sourcefile.txt');
figure;axes; % create figure
act='0';threshold=0;N=0;DATA=0;ii=0;
while ischar(act) % loop until end of file.
  ii=ii+1;N=0;
  while temp<threshold&&ischar(act) % loop until threshold is overflown (next step) or end-of-file is reached. 
    act=fgetl(fID);
    temp=temp+str2double(act);
    N=N+1;
  end
  line('xdata',ii,'ydata',temp/N,'Marker','o') % New point should appear

  %%%%%%%%%%%%// Change here
   drawnow;

threshold=threshold+0.5; % Continue with new stopping rule.
end
```

Therefore, once you draw a line, the figure should immediately update itself and so for each iteration, the figure should update with a new `line` object.

Comment: Wow... Simple and perfect solution.

Comment: @Crowley - It comes with years of experience :) I just make it look easy.  Glad it worked!

Comment: I had to wait a while.  You were too fast :-)

Comment: @Crowley - Oh hehe :) sorry :) I have a tendency to answer questions quickly.  Thanks for the accept!

Comment: Authors did not expect that something could be solved by pressing 9 keys to edit the code and that answer and test could take less than a minute :-)